# Download And Install apk from a link

Tags: android

I`am trying to download and install an apk from some link,

but for some reason i get an exception.

I have one method downloadfile() which downloading the file and a call

to and installFile() method, which supposed to install it in the device.

some code:

```
public void downloadFile()
{
    String fileName = "someApplication.apk";
    MsgProxyLogger.debug(TAG, "TAG:Starting to download");
    try
    {

        URL u = new URL(
                "http://10.122.233.22/test/someApplication.apk");

        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

            try
            {
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);

                try
                {
                    c.connect();


                    FileOutputStream f = context.openFileOutput(fileName,
                            context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                    try
                    {
                        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int len1 = 0;
                        int totsize = 0;
                        try
                        {
                            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                            {
                                totsize += len1;
                                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);// .write(buffer);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        f.close();
                        MsgProxyLogger.debug(TAG, TAG
                                + ":Saved file with name: " + fileName);

                                    InstallFile(fileName);


                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (ProtocolException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is the install file method:

```
 private void InstallFile(String fileName)
{
    MsgProxyLogger.debug(TAG, TAG + ":Installing file  " + fileName);

    String src = String.format(
            "file:///data/data/com.test/files/",
            fileName);

    Uri mPackageURI = Uri.parse(src);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    int installFlags = 0;
    try
    {
        PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo("com.mirs.agentcore.msgproxy",
                PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
        if (pi != null)
        {
            MsgProxyLogger.debug(TAG, TAG + ":replacing  " + fileName);

            installFlags |= PackageManager.REPLACE_EXISTING_PACKAGE;
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e)
    {
    }

    try
    {
        // PackageInstallObserver observer = new PackageInstallObserver();
        pm.installPackage(mPackageURI);
    } catch (SecurityException e)
    {
                       //!!!!!!!!!!!!!here i get an security exception!!!!!!!!!!!
        MsgProxyLogger.debug(TAG, TAG + ":not permission?  " + fileName);
    }
```

this is the exception details:
"Neither user 10057 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES".

and i have set in my main app that permission in the manifest.

anyone has any idea?

thanks,

ray.

Comment: your code is too clumsy,there is no need to catch that many exceptions,they should be used in only Exceptional cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot install APKs that way -- only applications that are part of the system firmware can do that.

You should be able to use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, with a MIME type of `application/vnd.android.package-archive` and a `Uri` pointing to your file. Note that this may not work on devices that do not have "allow non-Market installs" checked.

Comment: Is the download and save proccess is also wrong?
is there any way of saving the file not on the SDCARD? or mybe do something like save,install,delete ? 
Could you please past some example of this solution? Thanks.

Comment: Ive managed to do that, thanks! but general question: in which line in my question i coudlnt use(unless the app is in the firmware) ?

Comment: @rayman: You cannot call `installPackage()`. But you knew that already, since that is where your `SecurityException` was, so I am guessing I did not understand your follow-up question.

Comment: I didnt know what was the reason, why the system does throws me an SecurityException.. anyway.. thanks.

Comment: Tell me Mark, do you know if there is any way of controling the confirm_installtion pop-up screen to be displayed prior to the download, as happens in the Market?

Comment: This really isn't the right answer - the answer is in the exception. You can install from within the application just fine, providing the application has the INSTALL_PACKAGES permission in the manifest.

Comment: @Lee: do you have any evidence that `INSTALL_PACKAGES` can be held by applications other than those signed by the firmware signing key?

Answer (score 6):

You need add that permission to manifest
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: INSTALL_PACKAGES... a quick ctrl-f/cmd-f solves that quite quickly.