# install 2 apk files while installing one

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download And Install apk from a link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062685/download-and-install-apk-from-a-link)

hi.. 
Wen my application is being installed i also want to install Adobe reader apk.

Is it possible to add the Adobe Reader apk somewhere in my application so that it gets installed with my application?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want to force the install of adobe- what if they want to use some other pdf reader?  and everytime adobe updates their reader you want to update your code?

You could test to see if it is installed:

```
boolean readerInstalled= false;
try {
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.adobe.reader", 0);
  if (ai != null)
    readerInstalled= true;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  readerInstalled= false;
}
```

then provide a link to the market if they want to install it.